# Circumcentre of triangle question. Given ratios of areas, find ratios of lengths.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I just made this question up...

*Let ABC be a triangle with circumcentre O such that the ratio of the areas of the triangles $ABO: ACO: BCO$ is $2:3:4$. Find the ratios of the sides of the triangle $AB: BC: CA$.*

Of course the numbers $2:3:4$ are arbitrarily chosen. I'm just interested in how to solve this problem.

$$$$

What I tried: I let the radius of the circumcentre be $OA = OB = OC = r$, and let angle $AOB = \alpha_1$, angle $AOC = \alpha_2$, angle $BOC = \alpha_3$

I tried using the sine area rule for each triangle ABO, ACO, BCO, and got:

$$r^2 \sin\alpha_1 = 4  \qquad (1)$$ $$ r^2 \sin\alpha_2 = 6 \qquad (2)$$ $$r^2 \sin\alpha_3 = 8 \qquad(3)$$

and of course

$$ \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 360 ^\circ \qquad (4)$$

I tried a few things here but was not successful in making much progress. <s>We can of course let r=1 WLOG</s>.

The "R addition formulas" didn't seem to help.

Also, there are the "factor formulas" for $\sin:$ $ \quad sin x + \sin y \equiv 2 \sin(\frac{x+y}{2}) \cos(\frac{x-y}{2})$ ,

but this is for two terms only, and we have three terms in the above equations.

Edit: I also discovered this about arcsin: https://www.math-only-math.com/arcsin-x-plus-arcsin-y.html

We could apply it to $(1), (2) $ and $(3)$ (i.e. $\ \alpha_1 = \arcsin \frac {4} {r^2}, \ \alpha_2 = \arcsin \frac {6} {r^2}, and \ \alpha_3 = \arcsin \frac {8} {r^2}$ and then add these) and I tried this, but the expression we get at the end doesn't seem particularly helpful. It seems like a dead end to me.

So can we make progress using my current equations, or are there easier ways to do it? (Of course there are: I'm just interested in seeing the different methods).

Comment: Recall $\sin\frac{\alpha_1}{2}=\frac{\frac12 AB}{r}$ and the sums of the areas should give the area of the triangle. However, [the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*%284*r%5E2-x%5E2%29%3D64%2C+y%5E2*%284*r%5E2-y%5E2%29%3D12%5E2%2C+z%5E2*%284*r%5E2-z%5E2%29%3D16%5E2%2C+x*y*z%3Dr*4*%284%2B6%2B8%29) is not that simple. Maybe I have mistaken somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The area ratios are $\frac12r^2\sin\alpha_1 : \frac12r^2\sin\alpha_2 : \frac12r^2\sin\alpha_3=2:3:4$. Then, let

$$\sin\alpha_1 = 2x,\>\>\>\>\>\sin\alpha_2 = 3x,\>\>\>\>\>\sin\alpha_3 = 4x $$

Note that $\sin(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) = \sin(2\pi- \alpha_3)$, which is

$$2\sqrt{1-9x^2}+3\sqrt{1-4x^2}=4
$$

where it is assumed that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 > \frac\pi2$. Solve to get $x=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{16}$. Then,

$$\sin\alpha_1 = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{8},\>\>\>\>\>\sin\alpha_2 = \frac{3\sqrt{15}}{16},\>\>\>\>\>\sin\alpha_3 = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4} $$

and the side ratios are

\begin{align}
AB:BC:CA & = 2r\sin\frac{\alpha_1}2:2r\sin\frac{\alpha_3}2:2r\sin\frac{\alpha_2}2 \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha_1}2}:\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha_3}2}:\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha_2}2} \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{1+{\frac78}}2}:\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{1}{4}}2}:\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{11}{16}}2} \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{15}{16}}:\sqrt{\frac38}:\sqrt{\frac{27}{32}}
\end{align}

In the case of the circumcenter O outside the triangle ABC, we have $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2+\alpha_3 $, which, assuming $\alpha_3>\frac\pi2$, leads to

$$4\sqrt{1-9x^2}-3\sqrt{1-16x^2}=2\implies x=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{16}
$$
and the corresponding side ratios are

\begin{align}
AB:BC:CA & 
= \sqrt{\frac{15}{16}}:\sqrt{\frac 58}:\sqrt{\frac{5}{32}}
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: Great methods and tricks used here. I'm wondering if there's other solutions, i.e. for when $\alpha_1 \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $ or $ \alpha_2 \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $. I guess you can use similar methods.

Comment: I think you have to split it up into different cases, and it gets ugly.

Comment: @AdamRubinson - Another possibility is that O is outside ABC, which is added in the answer

Comment: Why does $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 + \alpha_3$ ? Wouldn't this imply $\alpha_1 = \pi $?

Comment: @AdamRubinson - See  the added graph in the answer

Comment: What is the formal reasoning that, if $O$ is outside the triangle, then the side $O$ is nearest to is $AB$ (i.e. not $AC$ or $BC$) ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson - because the area ABO is the smallest, hence largest angle

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. In particular, I've drawn a sketch where angle COB is about 100 degrees, angle COA is approx 60 degrees and angle AOB is approx 40 degrees. At least this looks like the areas are approximately in the ratios 2:3:4. You haven't explained why not: area ABO could be the smallest, and angle AOB could be the smallest angle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109625/discussion-between-quanto-and-adam-rubinson).

Comment: @AdamRubinson - interesting, it looks like another possibility, which corresponds to $\alpha_1+\alpha_2= \alpha_3$ and the side ratios are $\sqrt{\frac{1}{16}}:\sqrt{\frac 58}:\sqrt{\frac{5}{32}} $

Answer (score 0):

I would use Heron's formula of the area of a triangle:
$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$where$$s=\frac{a+b+c}2$$
Then for $\triangle ABO$, $s=\frac{2r+c}2=r+\frac c2$ and the area is $$A_{ABO}=\sqrt{(r+\frac c2)\cdot \frac c2\cdot \frac c2\cdot (r-\frac c2)}$$
You can write similar expressions for the other triangles. In case you need $r$, the formula for that is $$r=\frac{abc}{4A_{ABC}}$$

Comment: Did you mean the area of $A_{ABO}=\sqrt{(r+\frac c2)\cdot \frac c2\cdot \frac c2\cdot (r-\frac c2)}$, or am I mis-applying the formula?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks. My mistake

Comment: I've tried using this method (I've got 3 equations - one for each triangle using Heron's formula), but I still don't see how to get to an answer... The formula for r doesn't help either